# Generators and babel-node

Tags: javascript, generator, ecmascript-6, yield, babeljs

Not sure if it is my ES6 inexperience of something wrong with using Babel, but I am trying to create a sort of asynchronous if ... then

```
var token = 6;

var f1 = function*() {
    if (token > 5) {
        getToken();
        token = yield;
    }
    console.log(token);
};

var getToken  = function() {
    for (i=0; i<10000000; i++) {
        var x = i*2;
    }
    f1(0);
};

f1();
```

which I then run from its file with

```
babel-node generator.es6.js
```

I am expecting `0` but I don't get anything at all.

Comment: WTH is that loop supposed to do there? Is that a `sleep()`?

Comment: Yes. Something that goes off to the internet before returning a value

Comment: Well, something like that is *asynchronous* and should be simulated using a timeout, not a long-running loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call generator functions to create a generator, and then advance that using `.next()` calls:

```
function* f() {
    var token = 6;
    if (token > 5) {
        getToken();
        token = yield;
    }
    console.log(token);
};

function getToken() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        f1.next(0); // advance generator
    }, 100);
};

var f1 = f(); // create generator
f1.next(); // start generator
```

Notice that advancing the generator must be done asynchronously, calling it directly from `getToken` would have resulted in a `TypeError` from `f1.next()` while `f1` was still executing. It needs to reach the `yield` statement first.

Comment: Thanks - your comment about how to start a generator is something I would not have worked out immediately either, so thanks